# Apple script - How to show url link in dialog

Tags: macos, url, hyperlink, dialog, applescript

I wonder if there is any way to show an URL link in apple script dialog so that user is able to click the link and it automatically opens it.

Comment: Why not just code it to open the target URL if the user clicks OK or presses Enter. AFAIK There is no way with basic standard AppleScript to show a clickable hyperlink in a display dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to a solution like below,

```
osascript <<'END'
    set theAlertText to "Swiftlint is not installed"
    set theAlertMessage to "Download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint manually. Would you like to open link?"
    display alert theAlertText message theAlertMessage as critical buttons {"Cancel", "Open link"} default button "Open link" cancel button "Cancel" giving up after 60
    set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
    if the button_pressed is "Open link" then
        open location "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/README.md"
    end if
END
```